# Unable tochange user name in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 Login

Tags: sql-server

My problem is this. My friends changed my laptop Username. Later I changed it back to my name, but when I log in to SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 the previous user name appears. I can't change that because username field is disabled.

[image]

Thilina is previous windows username.

In the login panel this is what it shows.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to repro your issue where I was logged into SQL Server that identified me as WS1\Jeff but I was logged in using account WS1\Dan which is your same issue in reverse.

To fix this I followed these steps:

1. Open computer Management>>Expand Local Users and Groups, select the
   Users folder icon. Make sure both your both columns (Name and Full
   Name) say your name.

   - To change Name, right click then on the context menu click Rename.
   - To change Full Name, double click the Name, and to the properties dialog then change the Full Name value.

     2. Reboot if you changed either, not sure if this is needed but it will reinitialize all registry hives.
     3. **IMPORTANT: Login to SQL using SQL Server Authentication with username 'sa'. This is imperative so you do not lock yourself out of
        the server.**
     4. Delete your Windows account login from SQL Server logins.
     5. Add it back

        - **A.** Right click "Logins" >> click New User
        - **B.** Click Search in the new user dialog
        - **C.** Click "Advanced" button in
          the "Select User or Group" dialog window
        - **D.** Click "Find Now"
          Button and scroll for your Windows account.
        - **E.** Once you find your
          account, double click, then click OK on both "Select User or Group"
          dialogs but leave the "New User" dialog window open.
        - **F.** In the
          left list box, select "Server Roles" then in the right list box
          check boxes you want to have as server roles. I usually choose
          "ServerAdmin" and "SysAdmin"
        - **G.** Click Ok on the "New User" dialog
          window.
     6. Close SQL Management Studio
     7. Open SQL Management Studio, change to Windows Authentication and click Connect.
     8. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on SQL Server Management Studio and choose run different user and type your own credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same issue. I have followed the below steps. It worked.

1. Login into SQL Server Management Studio
2. select your server name -> security -> logins -> Right click and select new user.
3. enter the name and set the password
4. on left tab -> select Securables -> Under permissions window provide appropriate permissions
5. and try log in with the new user name.
6. delete the old one.